# Questions about electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism

- Are photons units of energy?
- What is the relation between EM force, EM energy and the photon?
- Do EM forces carry energy, do they carry the photon (as unit of energy)?

Comment: English would be preferable

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is currently not written in English.

Comment: Yep, questions on SE sites (except those dedicated to other languages) need to be in English. If anyone wants to edit this question to include a translation, I can reopen it then.

Comment: @DavidZ I had already translated it while you were cogitating on holding. I edited ,  so maybe you can open it?

Comment: @bobie I popped it into Google Translate too but the translation doesn't produce an intelligible result.  See above for example.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) (maybe the age of the questioner excuses not using it) :

> Photons are units of energy? That relationship between electromagnetic forces, electromagnetic energy and the photon? Electromagnetic forces, carry energy, (carring The energy), carry the photon (unit of energy?

No. Photons are [elementary particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg) they have mass zero, and can have any energy defined by E=h*nu where h is the [Planck constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) , and nu the frequency of the classical electromagnetic wave that would emerge from a great number of photons with this energy. They are not units of energy.

The classical electromagnetic field [carries energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector), but this is built up by a great number of photons that make up this electromagnetic field. Dividing the classical energy by h*nu will give the number of photons building up the classical wave.

The electric and magnetic fields observed macroscopically  can be mathematically described as limiting cases as the frequency of constituent photons goes to zero. There is no electromagnetic force, only electric and magnetic fields where charged particles can interact and see a classical force.

Note: one can use the link above for translating back to any language.

Nota: se puede utilizar el enlace de arriba para traducir de nuevo a cualquier idioma.